# How to specify For Each cell in entire column in Excel using a variable column number

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I am trying to process each filled cell in a single column of an Excel spreadsheet using VBA. Assuming my variable `thisCell` is a Range object, I can use:

```
For Each thisCell In Range("A:A")
```

This is OK, but I want a variable such as `ColToSort` (defined as a `Long`) to specify the column, not a string. The best I could come up with after 2 hours of searching and trying was this dog:

```
For Each thisCell In Range(Chr(64 + ColToSort) & ":" & Chr(64 + ColToSort))
```

Save me from having to create a string out of a perfectly good numeric variable here! And why is it not documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamically pointing to columns can, initially, be very confusing. I've done all sorts of things like mapping letters to numbers and the like. Thankfully there is the `columns()` object, which itself is a `range` type. I suspect what you are looking for is something more along the lines of:

```
 For Each thisCell In Sheet1.Columns(1).Cells
```

You can dynamically set the column number without having to muck around with figuring out which letter it is using this method.

Comment: I swear I tried something like that before, but yes, it works. I just now used "Columns(ColToSort).Cells", since this is a learning exercise, using the active sheet. Thank you!